# Cassandra shuts down immediately after startup

Tags: cassandra

We have unclustered, single-node Cassandra 3.11.2 instances supporting many separate customer environments.  Recently, we have seen many cases where a Cassandra instance is started, but then shuts down immediately and gracefully for no apparent reason.  The following are edited fragments from typical entries in the system.log files.

```
INFO  [main] 2023-07-30 00:53:59,514 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/.../conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2023-07-30 00:53:59,691 Config.java:495 - Node configuration:[ ... ]
...
<normal INFO-level messages>
...
INFO  [main] 2023-07-30 00:54:07,126 StorageService.java:2292 - Node <hostname>/<IP address> state jump to NORMAL
INFO  [main] 2023-07-30 00:54:07,139 AuthCache.java:172 - (Re)initializing CredentialsCache (validity period/update interval/max entries) (2000/2000/1000)
INFO  [main] 2023-07-30 00:54:07,142 Gossiper.java:1670 - Waiting for gossip to settle...
INFO  [main] 2023-07-30 00:54:15,144 Gossiper.java:1701 - No gossip backlog; proceeding
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2023-07-30 00:54:17,135 HintsService.java:220 - Paused hints dispatch
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2023-07-30 00:54:17,138 Gossiper.java:1540 - Announcing shutdown
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2023-07-30 00:54:17,140 StorageService.java:2292 - Node <hostname>/<IP address> state jump to shutdown
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2023-07-30 00:54:19,141 MessagingService.java:984 - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  [ACCEPT-<hostname>/<IP address>] 2023-07-30 00:54:19,142 MessagingService.java:1338 - MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2023-07-30 00:54:19,282 HintsService.java:220 - Paused hints dispatch
```

As shown above, a few seconds after the startup, Cassandra abruptly announces its shutdown with no error raised.  This is an intermittent error that happens often, but is still difficult to reproduce in isolation.

Cassandra has been running OK in the environments for some time without this issue, so I'm sure that recent environment changes must have triggered it.  However, so far I have been unable to find any root cause.  We are looking into the following possibilities but haven't found any problems yet.

1. Old Cassandra processes running in the O/S that were not properly shut down.
2. Port conflicts with other processes or firewall changes.
3. A shortage of allocated Cassandra memory, resulting in a silent crash or kill from the O/S.

We also see the following warnings during startup.

```
WARN  [main] 2023-07-30 00:54:00,017 NativeLibrary.java:187 - Unable to lock JVM memory (ENOMEM). This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out, especially with mmapped I/O enabled. Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK or run Cassandra as root.
WARN  [main] 2023-07-30 00:54:00,018 StartupChecks.java:136 - jemalloc shared library could not be preloaded to speed up memory allocations
WARN  [main] 2023-07-30 00:54:00,018 StartupChecks.java:169 - JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
INFO  [main] 2023-07-30 00:54:00,020 SigarLibrary.java:44 - Initializing SIGAR library
WARN  [main] 2023-07-30 00:54:00,038 SigarLibrary.java:174 - Cassandra server running in degraded mode. Is swap disabled? : false,  Address space adequate? : true,  nofile limit adequate? : true, nproc limit adequate? : true 
WARN  [main] 2023-07-30 00:54:00,040 StartupChecks.java:311 - Maximum number of memory map areas per process (vm.max_map_count) 262144 is too low, recommended value: 1048575, you can change it with sysctl.
```

However, in cases where have raised the vm.max_map_count and/or RLIMIT_MEMLOCK values, it hasn't had any affect besides removing the warning messages.

Are there any typical causes we should look for that might show these symptoms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the log sequence you posted, it looks like Cassandra kicks into a graceful shutdown. This is indicated by the messages from the `StorageServiceShutdownHook` thread which only gets called when a clean shutdown is initiated.

There is roughly 2 seconds' worth of messages missing between `00:54:15,144` and `00:54:17,135` so I would suggest reviewing the `debug.log` on the problematic node for clues as to the cause of the problem.

It would also be worth checking the commands being run on the machine particularly if you are using custom scripts for startup/shutdown. The reason I bring this up is that there is possibly a chance that a shutdown is being inadvertently called as evidenced by the messages from the `StorageServiceShutdownHook` thread. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After some investigation it is clear that I misdiagnosed the problem in my first post, so I am closing this question and will post another with different points and log entries. (In fact, Cassandra is being shut down by a client script, so unexpected shutdown is not the issue here.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! A friendly note to let you know I disagree on closing the question. My analysis of the problem correctly identified that the shutdown was expected so you should have accepted my answer. For guidance, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. Cheers!